# How can you update a checkbox in a MenuItem dynamically?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

This is my layout for a menu.

Notice the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_best_stores"
        android:title="@string/showStores"
        android:onClick="showHideStores"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

This is the onAction function.

```
public void showHideStores(MenuItem m) {
    m.setChecked(!m.isChecked());
    SHOWING_STORES = !SHOWING_STORES;
    showStoresProcess(SHOWING_STORES);
    refreshData();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();

}
```

Whenever I run my program, the function works because things that are supposed to happen, happen. Except, for the part where the ItemMenu itself changes... It just doesn't do anything, the checkbox stays unchecked... I also tried setTitle, doesn't change anything either.

So, line 1 isn't producing any change.

What is going on?

This is the code where I inflate the Menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_list_actions, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        refreshData();
        return true;
    }
```

Notice how the function works because the screen changes, but the menu itself doesn't get "checked off" or "unchecked".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you should the code where you are inflating the menu?

Comment: Use onOptionsItemSelected instead, as it's stated here  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable

Comment: check what `m.isChecked()` is returning for both states.

Comment: @CharlesDurham, I have appended it now, but it is nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is explained as follow:

- When you call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, it will reset to default menu. So nothing happened.

Solution: override [`onPrepareOptionsMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu))()

```
@override
public bool onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem m  = memenu.findItem(R.id.YourItemId);
    m.setChecked(!m.isChecked());//something like this

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your call to `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. Calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` is going trigger a call back to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` which is going to create a new menu which will create a new un-checked `MenuItem`, basically exactly what you don't want to halpen.